# Video.js cancelFullScreen api method not working in Firefox

Tags: javascript, html5-video, fullscreen, video.js

i am using [video.js](http://videojs.com/) to build a customised video player. One of the things i want to build into the functionality is a check to make sure that if the video ends playback whilst in full screen mode it drops back to normal mode. I figured this would be pretty easy to implement using the [video.js api](https://github.com/zencoder/video-js/blob/master/docs/api.md).

In my code i am listening for the "ended" event and then in the handler for this event firing the cancelFullScreen() method, and this works absolutely fine in Chrome (it even works in flash fallback mode for IE 7/8), but it is not working at all in Firefox 19 - the window just stays in full screen mode.

Any ideas why?

Here is my markup:

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://vjs.zencdn.net/3.2/video-js.css">
    <script src="http://vjs.zencdn.net/c/video.js"></script>

    <div class="vid_container" style="width: 934px; height: 524px; left: 0; top: 0;">
      <video id="video_NewMoon" controls   class="video-js vjs-default-skin" width="934" height="524" poster="/cms/arcadiacorp_uk/repository/pages/static/static-0000008447/images/poster.jpg" data-setup="{}">
        <source src="http://ecmcstg.arcadiagroup.ltd.uk/cms/arcadiacorp_uk/repository/pages/static/static-0000008447/flash/nailVid.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        <source src="http://ecmcstg.arcadiagroup.ltd.uk/cms/arcadiacorp_uk/repository/pages/static/static-0000008447/flash/nails.webm" type="video/webm">

        <a href="http://ecmcstg.arcadiagroup.ltd.uk/cms/arcadiacorp_uk/repository/pages/static/static-0000008447/flash/nailVid.mp4" title="Click here to download the video">Your browser cannot play this video, click here to download it instead.</a>
      </video>
    </div>
```

here is my js code that sits just inside the closing body tag:

```
var myPlayer = _V_("video_NewMoon");

var movEnded = function(){
    myPlayer.bigPlayButton.hide();
    myPlayer.loadingSpinner.hide();

    if(myPlayer.isFullScreen === true) {
        console.log("yep, we're fullscreen - lets shut this down");
        myPlayer.cancelFullScreen();
    }
};
myPlayer.addEvent("ended", movEnded);
```

I have tried various other methods to get round it such as trigger the Esc key with jquery in the ended handler but this didn't work either. I'm running out of patience with this now.

Oh and while we're on the subject of bugs, on ended the loading spinner shows on Chrome but is hidden in FF. I'd rather it were hidden to be honest.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

According to http://caniuse.com/fullscreen fullscreen API is partially supported in Firefox.